# Crontab scheduling for specific option

Tags: cron, aix, scheduling

I need to add a crontab entry which runs every quarter  ,on second sunday ,at 02 am.

Which of the below one is correct? the OS is AIX.

```
00 02 8-14 */3 0  &&  /myscript.sh
```

or

```
00 02 8-14 */3 * [ "$(date '+\%a')" == "Sun" ]  &&  /myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minutes, hours and month are correct.

There is an interaction between day of week and day of month. Your first version will run on every day from 8th to 14th, **and** on every Sunday (but not twice if e.g. the 11th is a Sunday).

From `man -s 5 crontab`:

> Note: The day of a command's execution can be specified by two fields
> — day of month, and day of week. If both fields are restricted (i.e.,
> aren't *), the command will be run when either field matches the
> current time.

Your second version may have two problems:

(1) It may be run by /bin/sh, or by some shell specified in the crontab. I'm not sure how portable the `==` is.

(2) The "Sun" is locale-specific.

I would probably sidestep these with `[ "$( date '+\%u')" -eq 7 ]`, but explained with a comment.

This results in

```
00 02 8-14 1,4,7,10 * [ "$(date '+\%u')" -eq 7 ] && /myscript.sh
```

Comment: is it not 0 for sunday? and is this the expected  one which will run correctly                            
00 02 8-14 */3 * [ "$(date '+\%u')" -eq 0 ] && /myscript.sh

Comment: also not the escape character for %

Comment: @user1929905  `crontab` will accept either 0 or 7 for Sunday. But `date '+\%u'` only emits `day of week (1..7); 1 is Monday`, so crontab will never get zero from the date check. You need to check the path for the script -- I doubt it is in /root, and I don't trust cron to evaluate `~` or `$HOME` as it does not read your profiles. But I believe the timing mechanism is correct.

Comment: 00 04 8-14 */3 * [ "$(date '+\%u')" -eq 7 ] && /home/mynane/myscript.sh    <---  does this looks good ?

Comment: @user1929905  Sure. I am on Linux. I checked `www.ibm.com/docs/en/aix/7.2?topic=c-crontab-command` and it does not mention the `step` operator, as in the month `*/3`. You probably need to pass the month as `1,4,7,10`. I am faking a test now like `00 18 1-3 2-12/3 * [ "$(date '+\%u')" -eq 2 ] && date >> /home/paul/CronTab.test` to get a result for today, and maybe with variations later.

Comment: did your test worked? do */3  for month will work? or it is best to pass 1,4,7,10?

Comment: if i mention /3  it gives error  crontab: error on previous line; unexpected character found in line.so i guess 1,4,7,10 is correct

Comment: @user1929905  My test showed the date test works (I ran for days 2 and 3).  I cannot run that crontab entry on AIX, but you could: it is safe -- it just appends a timestamp to a file. Your `crontab -e` may validate the edit, or it may just not get run, or it may work, or you might play safe and list the months.

Comment: 00 02 8-14 1,4,7,10 * [ "$(date '+\%u')" -eq 7 ] && /home/myname/myscript.sh    should be then correct..i accept your answer!